# vector of pointer to object - how to avoid memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, vector, observer-pattern

How do we ususaly deal with a vector whose elements are pointers to object? My specific question is the comment at the end of the code supplied below. Thanks.

```
class A
{
 public:
 virtual int play() = 0 ; 
};

class B : public A 
{
public:
 int play() {cout << "play in B " << endl;};

};

class C : public A 
{
public:
 int play() {cout << "play in C " << endl;};

};


int main()
{

    vector<A *> l;
    l.push_back(new B());
    l.push_back(new C());

    for(int i = 0 ; i < l.size();i++)
    {
            l[i]->play();
    }

    //Do i have to do this to avoid memory leak? It is akward. Any better way to do this? 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < l.size();i++)
    {
            delete l[i];
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you have to do that to avoid memory leak. The better ways to do that are to make a vector of shared pointers ([boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), C++TR1, C++0x, )

```
 std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<A> > l;
```

or vector of unique pointers (C++0x) if the objects are not actually *shared* between this container and something else

```
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> l;
```

or use boost [pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html)

```
  boost::ptr_vector<A> l;
```

PS: Don't forget A's virtual destructor, as per @Neil Butterworth!

Comment: Hello all, I am using VS2010 which may have shared_ptr. Is there an example I can take a look? --thx

Comment: @q0987 MSDN is a good place to start, in your case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982026.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Use an array of shared_ptr, or similar smart pointer. And note that your base class must have a virtual destructor for this code to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use smart pointers ([Boost shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)) to avoid this kind of things. But if you NEED to have raw pointers I believe this is the way to do it.