# C++ -- how to design the data structure so that it can avoid the memory leak

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [vector of pointer to object - how to avoid memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447804/vector-of-pointer-to-object-how-to-avoid-memory-leak)

Hello all,

I have the following code,

```
vector<Student*> vec;
// populate vec with Student pointers
```

Then `sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ...)` to sort the Student based on the score.

Here is the question,

Because vector stores the pointers, we have to later remember to remove it manually.
However, we cannot store auto_ptr inside the vector.

Is there a better way for this?
Store a smart pointer inside vector?
How to design this smart pointer?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Colin's answer- auto_ptr is not useful with containers as it can not be copied.  What you are looking for is a reference counted smart pointer- either a shared pointer or an intrusive pointer will do the job.  Boost supplies several smart pointers for you- including shared_ptr, and intrusive_ptr.  Most likely (infered from your original question) [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:
[boost smrtpntr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm), or you could template-specialize vector to delete the objects in it's destructor, which could have unintended consequences if not done carefully.

Answer (score 1):

On the flip side of using a vector of smart pointers, as Colin and MarkD have suggested, you could also use [boost::ptr_vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html)