# put pointer in std::vector & memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
class A {
public:
    void foo()
    {
        char *buf = new char[10];
        vec.push_back(buf);
    }

private:
    vector<char *> vec;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo();
    a.foo();
}
```

In `class A`, `foo()` allocates some memory and the pointer is saved to `vec`. When `main()` finishes, `a` will desconstruct, and so will `a.vec`, but will the allocated memory be released?

Comment: That's definitely a memory leak. You never `delete` your pointers.

Comment: No, you need to go through each element and free the memory (or use something better like `std::string`).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447804/vector-of-pointer-to-object-how-to-avoid-memory-leak?rq=1) is sort of the same idea.

Answer (score 4):

The memory will not be released. For it to be released, you need to put it in either a unique_ptr or a shared_ptr.

```
class A {
   public:
     void foo()
     {
        unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[10]);
        vec.push_back(buf);
     }
   private:
     vector<unique_ptr<char[]>> vec;
};
```

Comment: What if `vec` contains objects of a class, then when `vec` finishes, will it call the class's desctructor?

Comment: Alright, so there will be a memory leak for some types' pointers, such as `char *` and `int *`; but for classes which have allocated resources `deleted` in destructors, vector will call the destructors automatically, right?\

Comment: In your example, destructors will not be called if you use plain pointers for builtin types or user defined types. For the destructor to be invoked you need a smart pointer like unique_ptr or need to write a destructor for the A class.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could make a destructor

```
 ~A()
{
    for(unsigned int i =0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
         delete [] vec[i];
}
```

EDIT

As pointed out you need to make copy and assignment also (if you intend to use them that is)

```
class A
{
public:

    A& operator=(const A& other)
    {
        if(&other == this)
             return *this;

        DeepCopyFrom(other);

        return *this;
    }

    A(const A& other)
    {
        DeepCopyFrom(other);
    }


private:
    void DeepCopyFrom(const A& other) 
    {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < other.vec.size(); ++i) 
        {
            char* buff = new char[strlen(other.vec[i])];
            memcpy(buff, other.vec[i], strlen(other.vec[i]));
        }
    }

    std::vector<char*> vec;
};
```

More on the subject of deep copying and why you need it here

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/

Comment: And then a copy-constructor and assignment operator as well!

Comment: Yes that is true. Can add them when im not on my phone :)